# fill html form with data for SQL with php dropdown field

Tags: php, html, sql

I want to make a Recipe-Book where the user can make new recipes therefore he can choose from pre-entered ingredients from a dropdown field.

My code looks like this so far:

```
<html>
    <body>
    <form  method="post"  >
    <?php

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "tagebuch1";

    // LOGIN TO DATABASE SCRIPT WRITTEN FOR MYSQLI
    $mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " .            $mysqli->connect_error;
     }
    // END OF LOGIN TO DB SCRIPT
    $query_ak='SELECT * FROM privnahrungsmittel';
    $result = $mysqli->query($query_ak);
    ?>
    <select name="exa" >
        <?php
        while ($row =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo '<option value="'.$row['idprivNahrungsmittel'].'">'.$row['brennwert'].'</option>';
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="GO!"  name="go"/>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

But I only get an empty output like this, although the Table is filled with content:

[Dropdown field empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kth6C.png)

Can anyone pls advise where the mistake is?

Thank you

Comment: If your question doesn't matter - remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Please change `$row =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` to `$result->fetch_assoc()`

```
   while ($row =  $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row['idprivNahrungsmittel'].'">'.$row['brennwert'].'</option>';
    }
```